# Remainder of division of ${6}^{7^n}$ to $43$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

> What is the Remainder of the division of ${6}^{7^n}$ to $43$?

I've tried with Fermat's little theorem, but it haven't work.

Update : lab bhattacharjee gave a nice proof. But I want to know if *this* proof is correct.

${6^7}^n = ({6^7})^{7^{n-1}}$

$6^7 = ({6^3})^2$ * 6

$6^3 = 216 = 1(mod 43) => ({6^3})^2 = 1^2 = 1 (mod 43) => 6^7 = 6 (mod 43) => ({6^7})^{7^{n-1}} = 6^{7^{n-1}} (mod 43) <=> {6^7}^n = {6^7}^{n-1} (mod 43)$

The same way we obtain $6^{7^{n-1}} = 6^{7^{n-2}} (mod 43)$

$6^{7^{n-2}} = 6^{7^{n-3}} (mod 43)$

...

${6^7}^2 = {6^7}^1 (mod 43)$

${6^7}^1 = {6^7}^0 = 6 (mod 43)$

So ${6^7}^n = 6 (mod 43)$

Comment: $6^3=216\equiv 1(mod 43)$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Is it correct (the proof)?

Comment: @user3313320 sorry, writting mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\phi(43)=42$

$\implies6^{(7^n)}\equiv6^{7^n\pmod{42}}\pmod{43}$

let use find $7^n\pmod{42}$

Now as $(7^n,42)=7$ for integer $n\ge1$

we shall find $7^{n-1}\pmod6$

$7\equiv1\pmod6\implies7^{n-1}\equiv1^{n-1}\equiv1$

$\implies7^n\equiv7\cdot1\pmod{6\cdot7}\equiv7$

$\implies6^{(7^n)}\equiv6^7\pmod{43}$

Now use $6^3\equiv1\pmod{43}$ and $6^7=(6^3)^2\cdot6\equiv?\pmod{43}$

Comment: I can't get the second line with 6^(7^n) = 6^7^n (mod 42) (mod 43)...

Comment: @scummy, As $6^{42}\equiv1\pmod{43}$

Comment: I can undersant this, but still can't get the second line.

Comment: @scummy, If $7^n=42m+r,$   $$6^{(7^n)}\equiv6^{42m+r}=(6^{42})^m\cdot6^r\equiv1^m\cdot6^r\pmod{43}$$

Comment: Sorry - just didn't see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As $6^3\equiv1\pmod{43}$  $$6^{(7^n)}\equiv6^{(7^n)\pmod3}\pmod{43}$$

and $7\equiv1\pmod3\implies7^n\equiv1^n\equiv1$

$$6^{(7^n)}\equiv6^1\pmod{43}$$

Comment: @scummy, Please clarify your question.

Comment: Could we speak at chat? It's quite hard here 'cause you can edit a comment every 5 minutes.

Comment: I've sent it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26895/room-for-scummy-and-lab-bhattacharjee)